# Database templates

Tags: database-design, schema, database-diagrams

Are there any site with database templates for specific purposes? (i.e. a database schema for users and authentication in a webpage) for different databases like Oracle, MySQL...

I have been looking in the Web but I didn't find anything and I think it would be very useful to share this knowledge. What I found are images of schemas that are useful also.

Answer (score 3):

There is a very good aggregation of resources on the following link

> http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models